# how to retain positions for images in fabric js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to work on image processing with fabric js.I am dealing with very huge images hence I have to save copy of canvases after image processing so that next time it can be shown faster with jquery's id.show.
 But I want to render the images on the exact location. I am using `canvas.zoomToPoint and canvas.relativePan` to zoom and pan the image but after I do zoom + pan and then apply image processing to show hidden canvas and apply `hiddencanvas.zoomToPoint and hiddencanvas.relativePan` on hidden canvas, it doesn't render the image on the exact location where I left the older canvas.
 Am I doing any mistake. Here's a supporting [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/96pas3z3/2/) .However, the fiddle renders a image by uploading and if you zoom and pan and click on invert, the inverted image doesn't move there Panning code :               `                 ``var panning = false;
        canvas.on('mouse:up', function (e) {
            panning = false;
        });

```
    canvas.on('mouse:down', function (e) {
        panning = true;
    });
    canvas.on('mouse:move', function(e) {
        if (panning && e && e.e) {
             var x = e.offsetX, y = e.offsetY;
             var delta = new fabric.Point(e.e.movementX, e.e.movementY);
             canvas.relativePan(delta);
             //Above statement pan's the image but what to save to server in order to render the image on the exact panned location ?
        }
    });
```

`` whereas this is zoom code : `canvas.zoomToPoint({ x: x, y: y }, newZoom);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer , it was a very silly mistake .

Every canvas has a Viewport transform .
So, we just need to get `canvas.viewportTransform` and then we can get the ScaleX, scaleY, left , top as [scaleX, 0,0, scaleY, left,top] .

Hope , it will help someone .